Expectation of a piecewise const approximation based on Beta distribution
Let $X_1, X_2 \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ and then sort $X_1,X_2$ to get $X_{(1)} < X_{(2)}$.
Based on the pdfs of $X_{(i)}$, we know $X_{(1)} \sim \mathrm{Beta}(1,2)$  and $X_{(2)} \sim \mathrm{Beta}(2,1)$, with $\mathbb{E}(X_{(1)}) = \frac{1}{3}$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_{(2)}) = \frac{2}{3}$.
Consider the following piecewise constant approximation for the function $f(x) = x$.

Sample two points $x_1, x_2$ uniformly on $(0, 1)$ and them sort them to get $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(2)}$, $x_{(1)} <  x_{(2)}$. Denote the expectation as $\mathbb{E}_1(\|f - c\|_2^2) = \mathbb{E}_1(\displaystyle\int_{x_{(1)}}^{x_{(2)}} (f(t)-c)^2 \; dt)$, where $c = \frac{1}{x_{(2)}-x_{(1)}}\displaystyle\int_{x_{(1)}}^{x_{(2)}} f(t)\; dt$ is a constant.

Sample $y_{(1)}$ from $\mathrm{Beta}(1,2)$ and $y_{(2)}$ from $\mathrm{Beta}(2,1)$. Denote the Expectation as $\mathbb{E}_2(\|f - c\|_2^2) = \mathbb{E}_2(\displaystyle\int_{y_{(1)}}^{y_{(2)}} (f(t)-c)^2 \; dt)$, where $c = \frac{1}{y_{(2)}-y_{(1)}}\displaystyle\int_{y_{(1)}}^{y_{(2)}} f(t)\; dt$ is a constant.


(Note: the definitions of $\mathbb{E}_1$ and $\mathbb{E}_2$ are identical; the only difference is the method of obtaining the points $x_{(i)}, y_{(i)}$.)
Compare $\mathbb{E}_1(\|f - c\|_2^2)$ and $\mathbb{E}_2(\|f - c\|_2^2)$. It's observed from the numerical experiments that $\mathbb{E}_1(\|f - c\|_2^2) < \mathbb{E}_2(\|f - c\|_2^2)$. This result confuses me a lot.
First, I expect them to be equal because both $x_{(i)}$ and $y_{(i)}$ from the same Beta distribution as discussed above.
Second, even if $\; \mathbb{E}_1 \neq \mathbb{E}_2$, since $y_{(1)}$ could be greater than $y_{(2)}$, $\displaystyle\int_{y_{(1)}}^{y_{(2)}} (f(t)-c)^2 \; dt$ could be negative for some $y_{(i)}$. However, we know $\int_{x_{(1)}}^{x_{(2)}} (f(t)-c)^2 \; dt > 0$.
Therefore, shouldn't it be $\mathbb{E}_1(\|f - c\|_2^2) > \mathbb{E}_2(\|f - c\|_2^2)$?
I am confused by this result. Did I miss something? My experiments were done using Matlab with the built-in functions $\textit{rand}$ and $\textit{betarnd}$.
